# Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10128]: line 4:7 Not yet supported place for UDAF

Tags: sql, database, hive, hiveql, hue

I have tried to use the correlation function in a hive, But it provides the following error for me

**Error:**

> Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error
>   10128]: line 4:7 Not yet supported place for UDAF like sum, avg, etc..

What I am trying to do is I have 3 columns like a, b, c. I have to do the `corr()` function against the `avg(a,b)` and `c`.

My Query is

```
    select 
        (avg(a) + avg(b) / 2) as rateA, 
        avg(c) rateB, 
        corr( rateA, rateanyonefrom servey
```

Can any one please help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with your query,

You cannot have alias of one column in the same select clause.

Try `select corr(rateA, rateB), rateA, rateB from (select (avg(a) + avg(g) / 2) as rateA, avg(c) as rateB from tableName) t1;`

Hope this helps

Comment: It returns null value

Comment: select corr(rateA, rateB) from (select (avg(a) + avg(b) / 2) 
as rateA, avg(c) as rateB from tableName group by state_name) t1; This is my Query. I have to list down the rateA and rateB also in the select list

Comment: then you have to add the columns which you need in outer select query as well